# Android updade Array content / content

Tags: java, android, arrays

I got an array of booknames like this:

```
String[] booknames = {"book1","book2","book3"};
```

This is shown inside my app.
Now, what would be the best solutions to update so to say my booklist.

For instance if I want to add "book4" and "book5", even if the application is public.

Comment: I removed the sql tag because this appears to have nothing to do with databases.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to add items to their list you could use implementations of `List` interface, i.e. `ArrayList`. in this case yours code will be

```
String[] booknames = {"book1","book2","book3"};
ArrayList<String> listOfBooksNames=new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(booknames ));
listOfBooksNames.add("book4");
listOfBooksNames.add("book5");
```

And you can't add items to arrays, because they have fixed size;

Comment: Thanks so do I have to update the code and upload it everytime?